# CNN feed forward or back propagtion model

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Is convolutional neural network (CNN) a feed forward model or back propagation model. I get this confusion by comparing the blog of [DR.Yann](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/lenet/) and Wikipedia definition of CNN.

Comment: CNN is feed forward. By CNN is learning by backward passing of error.

Comment: A feed foward model can also be a back propagation model at the same time... this is mostly the case.

Answer (score 13):

A convolutional neural net is a structured neural net where the first several layers are sparsely connected in order to process information (usually visual).

A feed forward network is defined as having no cycles contained within it. If it has cycles, it is a recurrent neural network. For example, imagine a three layer net where layer 1 is the input layer and layer 3 the output layer. A feed forward network would be structured by layer 1 taking inputs, feeding them to layer 2, layer 2 feeds to layer 3, and layer 3 outputs. A recurrent neural net would take inputs at layer 1, feed to layer 2, but then layer two might feed to both layer 1 and layer 3. Since the "lower" layer feeds its outputs into a "higher" layer, it creates a cycle inside the neural net.

Back propagation, however, is the method by which a neural net is trained. It doesn't have much to do with the structure of the net, but rather implies how input weights are updated.

When training a feed forward net, the info is passed into the net, and the resulting classification is compared to the known training sample. If the net's classification is incorrect, the weights are adjusted backward through the net in the direction that would give it the correct classification. This is the backward propagation portion of the training.

So a CNN is a feed-forward network, but is trained through back-propagation.

Answer (score 1):

In short,
CNN is feed forward Neural Network.
Backward propagation is a technique that is used for training neural network.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to tswei's answer but perhaps more concise.

A convolutional Neural Network is a feed forward nn architecture that uses multiple sets of weights (filters) that "slide" or convolve across the input-space to analyze distance-pixel relationship opposed to individual node activations.

Backward propagation is a method to train neural networks by "back propagating" the error from the output layer to the input layer (including hidden layers).